# UTCDate in EventLog? Convert to correct locale

Tags: .net, utc

I am reading windows eventlog using WMI and just noticed recently that time is lagging behind, if I convert cim datetime to .NET.  It seems that datetime is encoded as UTC.  There should be straighforward conversion in .NET, isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try date.ToLocalTime() to convert an UTC date/time to local date/time.